# Monitoring cassandra disk space with jmx

Tags: cassandra, load, storage, monitoring, jmx

When I tried to monitor Cassandra_node with JMX, I had a problem.

In detail, I got a negative value from `jmx["org.apache.cassandra.metrics:type=Storage,name=Load","Count"].`

In Cassandra Wiki, the definition of this metrics is:

> Total disk space used (in bytes) for this node

Is it possible to get a negative value from this metrics? and why?

Comment: Perhaps a problem when casting value from 64 bit integer to 32 bit variable. How do you retrieve JMX values ?

Comment: I used jconsole and the type of value is long.

Answer (score 1):

Yes its possible. It depends a bit on version but there were some bugs like [CASSANDRA-8205](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-8205) and [CASSANDRA-7239](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-7239) in particular around the load. If its operating like it should, those will be accurate though.

You can always drop down to OS level and monitor it by looking at `du` on the data directory.

Comment: its a linux command for disk usage. can `du -sh /var/lib/cassandra/data` for example can get total disk space for all keyspaces. can then also look per keyspace